# С# Вставка и редактирование SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

На ms sql server. Есть 3 связанные таблицы - Students, Teachers, Diploma. В Diploma хранятся ID студентов и преподавателей и название темы дипломной работы. Из Windows формы вводится информация -  имена и тема. Т.к. в таблице хранятся не ID а имена.. Напрямую сохранять не получается. Приходится узнавать ID по имени два раза, запоминать в переменные. Потом только записывать. Можно ли реализовать как-то одним запросом в SQL.

Comment: Одним запросом вставить данные в две таблицы? не-а...

Comment: В одну.. в ней хранятся ID а пользователь вводит имя (2). Как одним запросом (зная имена) подтянуть ID из других таблиц и записать их (редактировать).

Comment: а не проще использовать выпадающий список и наследованный от стандартного лист итем, но расширенный свойством идентификатора или моделью персоны, тогда вам достаточно получит идентификаторы и отправить их в запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO diploma (student_id, teacher_id, diploma_subject)
SELECT student.id, teacher.id, 'The subject of diploma'
FROM student
CROSS JOIN teacher
WHERE student.name = 'Василий Пупкин'
  AND teacher.name = 'Идиосинкразий Парамонович Зипер-Молниеносный';
```

Предполагается, что на `student.name` и `teacher.name` в структурах таблиц наложено ограничение уникальности. Иначе во `WHERE` должны использоваться (вместо или в дополнение к) условия отбора, однозначно идентифицирующие соответствующие персонажи.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте хранимые процедуры передайте все значения и в ней добавьте 2, 3 сколько нужно записей в нужные таблицы